# Purple screen crash on Mac

Tags: mac, graphics-card, intel-graphics, osx-el-capitan, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm using a MacBook Pro mid 2010 with the latest Mac Os X El Capitan.

Today, when seeing images form an external drive the Mac froze with the following purple screen:

[image]

I had to restart the computer.

Anybody experienced this before?

Comment: To me, it looks like you graphics crapped out on you. Do you know if you have a dedicated graphics or integrated?

Comment: I have both, but the change between them doesn't work well anymroe in El Capitan

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the graphics card has just died. Have you tried resetting the SMC?

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295